# Inheritance in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I am using inheritance in hibernate, 
I have **Table** Atom, Person and Company in database . I need do this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Atom {
    ....
}

public abstract class Contact extends Atom {
    ....
}

@Entity
public class Person extends Contact {
    .......
}

@Entity
public class Company extends Contact {
    .....
}
```

Contact Have not table.

I can not make contact as a Entity because it has no table. I Intended place the same class annotation that Atom

```
@Entity
@Inheritance (strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class extends Atom Contact
```

but search the Contact table and that table does not exis

Comment: I'd say `Atom` and `Contact` should actually be annotated with `MappedSuperClass`. Is there actually a table for `Atom`?

Comment: If Contact has no table why are you creating a class?

Comment: @Thomas Atom is parent of other class, Atom have a Table. Contact have properties commons to Person and Company

Comment: @AlfredoO I want no have a table for Contact

Comment: What's the data for `Atom`? - Also note that the inheritance strategy `JOINED` would require a table for `Contact` otherwise that joining would not work. Alternatively make the common properties an embeddable object and embed that into `Company` and `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

Read these docs for more information on MappedSuperclasses:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html